# What does "joint discourse" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

[Ngo,2021](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/13504851.2021.1904105) mentioned

> Using the Term Frequency-Inverse Document Frequency text-mining
> technique and a large dataset of tweets, we determined that the public
> sentiment on **joint discourses** of COVID-19 and financial topics was a
> strong driver of recent stock and cryptocurrency markets behaviour.

I try to google but I cannot see this phrase in dictionaries.
Apart from that, when I google the word "[discourse](https://www.thoughtco.com/discourse-language-term-1690464#:%7E:text=Discourse%20is%20a%20joint%20activity,situation%20of%20the%20communication%20itself.)" separately, the meaning is

> Discourse is a joint activity requiring active participation from two
> or more people, and as such is dependent on the lives and knowledge of
> two or more people as well as the situation of the communication
> itself

I am wondering that in the meaning of "discourse", we have the "joint activity" meaning already, so what does "joint discourse" mean? Does it simply mean "communication" ?

Comment: hint: there are two *topics* mentioned.

Comment: Possibly this is a technical term. Maybe something from an academic topic?

Comment: While *discourse* means a joint discussion, the added *joint* above refers to the joining of the areas of Covid-19 and financial topics. So, the discussions are joined, or *joint*, in two senses.